# Call to jFrame from jInternalFrame does not work

Tags: java, swing

I have a main jFrame `HomePage.java` and many other classes which extend `javax.swing.JInternalFrame`. One of the classes (JInternalFrame) is `Login.java`. Now I check whether the password is correct in `Login.java` and if the password is correct, I load `success.java`. Now the problem arises when I have to load the `success.java` page.
I have a function in the `HomePage.java` whose purpose is to remove all internal frames and load success.java class. The function is as follows :-

```
public void LogIn(){
    jDesktopPane1.removeAll();
    System.out.println("Pos 2");
    success frame = new success();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    jDesktopPane1.add(frame);
    setContentPane(jDesktopPane1);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
    }
}
```

I call the function in the Login.java page as follows :-

```
System.out.println("Pos 1 ");
(new HomePage()).LogIn();
```

The logic does not work. But, I receive the output as

```
Pos 1
Pos 2
```

which shows that the program flow was correct. I do not get any error also. Another weird factor is that when I calthe same `LogIn()` function from the menu in the jFrame itself, I get the desired output. Please solve my dilemma. Any help will surely be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
System.out.println("Pos 1 ");
(new HomePage()).LogIn();
```

Creates a ***new*** HomePage object and calls a method on it. Oh you are certainly calling the correct method, and it's going a HomePage instance, but it's not the correct HomePage instance, not the one that's displayed, because you've created a ***new*** one.

Short term solution: get a valid reference to the displayed HomePage instance and call your method on it. You could get it by passing it into the class that needs it as a constructor or method parameter, or you could use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(...)`.

i.e.,

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Login.this);
if (window instanceof HomePage) {
  HomePage validHomePageRef = (HomePage) window;
  validHomePageRef.logIn();
}
```

Long term solution: don't create spaghetti code with GUI objects changing behaviors of other GUI objects, but instead refactor your code a la MVC or one of its variants, so the GUI can change the model and the other GUI objects can be notified of these changes via listeners and respond if they want.

Comment: +1 for SwingUtilities. But how would one "validly refer" to the HomePage instance

Comment: @h2O: His HomePage object appears to be the JFrame that holds all the other parts of his GUI. If he gets that window, casts it to a HomePage variable, he has access.

Comment: @puZZlr: you're welcome, but I have to say, it's a bad design. Also you really need to learn and follow Java naming conventions including giving methods and variable names that start with lower-case letters and classes names that start with upper case letters.